# WebSuperGoo.ABCpdf8

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, using

I'm combing through a massive program for work that was worked on previously by 4-5 other programmers and ironing out the errors. I've come across an error involving the following line of code at the beginning of the file:

```
using WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8;
```

it's giving the following error: "The type or namespace name 'WebSupergoo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I know this is due to a reference I haven't included, and I found the website that has the files for it. But I can't figure out how to bring in the reference. I created a reference using the .dll file and then I included the reference, but I'm still getting the error. I don't have permission to post the program online, but I can give more details if necessary.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. If you need more information, feel free to ask.
Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but did you manage to solve this and if so do you remember how? I ran into the same problem with a received project.

Answer (score 2):

Check if .NET Target framework version of your project is not lower than the framework used for building ABCpdf.dll.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be too helpful at this point.  But I struggled with this as well from an inherited project after a Windows Update broke a very old implementation of ABCPDF within an ASP.NET web application.  I am not saying you should repeat these steps, but I am putting all these steps in here in case it helps someone else identify what they might need to do. Also, I was on ABCPDF10, but I don't see why this wouldn't work for any version.

1. I deleted all the ABCPDF files out of the project and bin/ manually including the ABCPDF.dlls, the ABCGecko.exe, the XUL Directory, and the PrintHooks.dlls.
2. I removed all the references to all those files in the proejct.csproj file
3. I removed all the Packages out of the ../packages for ABCPDF and ABCPDF.Gekco
4. I then installed 64-bit ABCPDF10, and then installed 32-bit ABCPDF10 via the MSI for each.
5. I then copied the files from their respective C:/Program Files directories into the bin/ of my project manually per ABCPDFs instructions.  This didn't work for me because when I went to build in VS2015 it couldn't see the .DLL for some reason.
6. I then uninstalled it by deleting the files out of my project bin/ manually and then using Add/Remove Apps in Server2012R2.
7. I then used Nuget to download ABCPDF and that worked and it could build.  But I still needed ABCPDF.Gekco
8. I then used Nuget to try and install ABCPDF.Gecko.  This downloaded it, but it didn't install it fully.  I manually copied over the missing .dlls and .exe into the bin/ directory and Built the project.
9. But at this point I got an error that it couldn't find the x64.dll even though it was in the bin/
10. What worked for me here is I left the Project and bin/ directory alone and I then used the .MSI installer and re-installed only the x64 version to the C:/ like any other program.  I didn't have to copy any files to the bin/.  I just re-built the project and boom!  That worked.

It *feels to me* like a registry key/path issue.  But I have no idea if that is right.

Hopefully that helps someone else.